# `recenter` issue in `xref-go-back` when using `lsp-mode`

Tags: lsp-mode, scrolling, xref, recenter

I have the below setting in my config as recommended by many scrolling packages like `ultra-scroll-mac`.

```
(setq scroll-conservatively 101)
```

The issue is, when using this config with `lsp-mode`, `xref-go-back` will not recenter the point to the middle of the window, but instead it recenter the point to the bottom of the window.

For example, before `xref-find-definitions`

[image]

after `xref-find-definitions`

[image]

after `xref-go-back`

[image]

I tested in a `emacs -q` settings with the config below, I am not sure if it's a `lsp-mode` issue so I have not reported it there. Also the issue is gone if `scroll-conservatively` is `0` or not using `lsp-mode` (e.g. using `xref-go-back` in plain `emacs-lisp-mode`).

I tried something like

```
(defun xref-go-back-fixes (orig-func &rest args)
    (let ((scroll-conservatively 0))
      (apply orig-func args)))
  (advice-add 'xref-go-back :around #'xref-go-back-fixes)
```

But it does not work. Unless I eval `(setq scroll-conservatively 0)` in the minibuffer, the issue is still there.

Any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated!

```
;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

(defvar elpaca-installer-version 0.6)
(defvar elpaca-directory (expand-file-name "elpaca/" user-emacs-directory))
(defvar elpaca-builds-directory (expand-file-name "builds/" elpaca-directory))
(defvar elpaca-repos-directory (expand-file-name "repos/" elpaca-directory))
(defvar elpaca-order '(elpaca :repo "https://github.com/progfolio/elpaca.git"
                              :ref nil
                              :files (:defaults "elpaca-test.el" (:exclude "extensions"))
                              :build (:not elpaca--activate-package)))
(let* ((repo  (expand-file-name "elpaca/" elpaca-repos-directory))
       (build (expand-file-name "elpaca/" elpaca-builds-directory))
       (order (cdr elpaca-order))
       (default-directory repo))
  (add-to-list 'load-path (if (file-exists-p build) build repo))
  (unless (file-exists-p repo)
    (make-directory repo t)
    (when (< emacs-major-version 28) (require 'subr-x))
    (condition-case-unless-debug err
        (if-let ((buffer (pop-to-buffer-same-window "*elpaca-bootstrap*"))
                 ((zerop (call-process "git" nil buffer t "clone"
                                       (plist-get order :repo) repo)))
                 ((zerop (call-process "git" nil buffer t "checkout"
                                       (or (plist-get order :ref) "--"))))
                 (emacs (concat invocation-directory invocation-name))
                 ((zerop (call-process emacs nil buffer nil "-Q" "-L" "." "--batch"
                                       "--eval" "(byte-recompile-directory \".\" 0 'force)")))
                 ((require 'elpaca))
                 ((elpaca-generate-autoloads "elpaca" repo)))
            (progn (message "%s" (buffer-string)) (kill-buffer buffer))
          (error "%s" (with-current-buffer buffer (buffer-string))))
      ((error) (warn "%s" err) (delete-directory repo 'recursive))))
  (unless (require 'elpaca-autoloads nil t)
    (require 'elpaca)
    (elpaca-generate-autoloads "elpaca" repo)
    (load "./elpaca-autoloads")))
(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'elpaca-process-queues)
(elpaca `(,@elpaca-order))


(elpaca elpaca-use-package
  (elpaca-use-package-mode)
  (setq elpaca-use-package-by-default t))

(elpaca-wait)

(setq use-package-verbose nil
      use-package-enable-imenu-support t
      use-package-always-defer t)

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.rs\\'" . rust-ts-mode))

(use-package lsp-mode
  :defer 3
  :diminish (lsp-mode)
  :hook ((rust-ts-mode)
         . (lambda () (run-with-idle-timer 0.2 nil #'lsp-deferred))))

(use-package lsp-rust
  :elpaca nil
  :demand t
  :after (:all lsp-mode rust-ts-mode)
  :init (setq lsp-rust-clippy-preference "on"
              lsp-rust-analyzer-cargo-watch-command "clippy"))

(elpaca-wait)
```

Comment: It does sound like an lsp-mode issue (with a bug report). But to confirm that it's not somehow a limitation of the LSP protocol, you can also try reproducing this problem with eglot.

Comment: @Dmitry After a quick test, I found that the same issue exists with `eglot`.

Comment: Ah yeah, I can reproduce this with Elisp too. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in fact one of the effects of setting `scroll-conservatively`: when a point moves inside a buffer, the window is scrolled in this particular way.

Anyway, to solve this specifically for `xref-go-back`, at least, you can add `recenter` to `xref-after-return-hook`.

Just like in `xref-after-jump-hook` where it's already present.

Comment: Strange, I can not reproduce this in non `lsp-mode`s . Anyway, your answer solved the question. Thank you very much for helping to fix this long-live super annoying issue for me. And I like you `company` package.

Comment: You're welcome!